# Need parallaxScroll on UICollectionView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview, uicollectionview, scrollview

I have a `UIView` on top of `UICollectionView`.

I want `parallaxScroll` effect on `UIview` during `UICollectionView` scroll

If any one have an idea help me out.

Answer (score -1):

paralax effect you can make like this:

```
//crteate vertical effect
UIInterpolatingMotionEffect *verticalMotionEffect =
[[UIInterpolatingMotionEffect alloc]
 initWithKeyPath:@"center.y"
 type:UIInterpolatingMotionEffectTypeTiltAlongVerticalAxis];
verticalMotionEffect.minimumRelativeValue = @(-50);
verticalMotionEffect.maximumRelativeValue = @(50);

// Set horizontal effect
UIInterpolatingMotionEffect *horizontalMotionEffect =
[[UIInterpolatingMotionEffect alloc]
 initWithKeyPath:@"center.x"
 type:UIInterpolatingMotionEffectTypeTiltAlongHorizontalAxis];
horizontalMotionEffect.minimumRelativeValue = @(-70);
horizontalMotionEffect.maximumRelativeValue = @(70);

// Create group to combine both
UIMotionEffectGroup *group = [UIMotionEffectGroup new];
group.motionEffects = @[horizontalMotionEffect, verticalMotionEffect];

// Add both effects to your object
[myObject addMotionEffect:group];
```

Comment: I do not know if it solves your problem directly, but in the variable 'group' is parallax effect can be used on any UIView or UIImage, or some other object.

Comment: nothing happens when add these effects to my uiview